# how to get position of a cell of a particular row on clicked of a table

Tags: javascript, sapui5

A basic question, but stuck on how to,

I have a table like below:

```
col0  col1  col2  col3  col3  col5
row1 | A  |   B |   C |  D  |  E
row2 | X  |   Y |   Z |  S  |  T
```

I am looking for a solution like if I click on `A` how to get the value of its position as `1`, if `B` `2` similarly `X` `1`....?

I was doing it like below:{tried with different scenario}

```
new sap.ui.core.Icon({

            press : function(evt) {

                   var source=evt.getSource();

                      var iconIndex=evt.mParameters.id; 
                      var iconIndexValue=iconIndex.split('-'); #{iconIndex = "__icon13-container-........}
                      var indexnumber=iconIndexValue[0].substring(6);#{13}
                        .......}
              ....
```

The issue I am facing using above method is when page on loaded , if I select `A` the value I get is `6` which is next set of position values , but when I refresh the page It is again `1`.

Is there any different approach to get as above?

I am also stuck on how to explain this in breif, but I guess the above expected result makes sense..

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: The [ListItemBase](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListItemBase) seems to have a `counter` property ... That looks promising (the description isn't really helpfup thpugh, maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: I should have actually mentioned the Icon in which I am trying this, added this in code, please check

Comment: Which table are we talking about? `sap.m.Table` or `sap.ui.table.*` tables? And what are you trying to achieve by having the position of the cell?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann sap.m.Table , with the position i want to change some css of icon in that position

Comment: @Codenewbie Looks like we're having an [_xy-problem_](http://xyproblem.info/) here as accessing elements by cell position is quite an error-prone practice. Please enhance the question with screenshots, mockups, and more descriptions of what you're **actually** trying to achieve.

Comment: sure thing, I will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you need to know the clicked cell position. You can achieve it by table methods like `indexOfItem()` and `indexOfCell()`

**View.xml**

```
<Table items="{/items}">
    <columns>
        <Column> <Text text="Amount" /> </Column>
        <Column> <Text text="Quantity" /> </Column>
        <Column> <Text text="Weight" /> </Column>
        <Column> <Text text="Status" /> </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Link text="{Amount}" press="getCellInfo" />
                <Link text="{Quantity}" press="getCellInfo" />
                <Link text="{Unit}" press="getCellInfo" />
                <Link text="{parameter1}" press="getCellInfo" />                    
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

**Controller.js**

```
getCellInfo: function(oEvent) {
    var oCell = oEvent.getSource();
    var oRow = oCell.getParent();
    var oTable = oRow.getParent();
    console.log("Row: "  + oTable.indexOfItem(oRow) + " Cell index: ", oRow.indexOfCell(oCell));        
},
```